# Angular 6 pipe operations remove typing from observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I just updated from *Angular5* to *6*. After updating I ran the code to migrate to *rxjs6* and it changed my code where I was using `takeWhile`. Now in order to subscribe to a service my code looks like this:

```
this.menuService.currentMenu.pipe(takeWhile(() => this.isAlive))
   .subscribe(result => { 
      if(result && result.name)
      {
         //do stuff
      }
   }
);
```

using this `import` statement

```
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

After looking at the docs for *rxjs6* it looks like this is the correct way to use `takewhile` now; however I am getting errors saying:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'

It looks like the `takewhile` operation is stripping the `observable` of its typing. It also happens with `filter` so I assume that `pipe` is the issue.

When I set up a test in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-subscription-example-takewhile?file=src/app/app.component.ts) I dont get the error, I expect this is might be do to the project in stackblitz not being on the same *typescript* version?

This is the version I am using:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.4.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.0.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core               0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics         0.6.8
@angular/cdk                       6.2.1
@angular/cli                       6.0.8
@angular/material                  6.2.1
@angular/material-moment-adapter   6.2.1
@ngtools/webpack                   6.0.8
@schematics/angular                0.6.8
@schematics/update                 0.6.8
rxjs                               6.2.1
typescript                         2.7.2
webpack                            4.8.3
```

**Edit:**
Explicitly specifying a type fixes the issue. But I don't see why I should have to, why it cant just keep its typing.

```
this.menuService.currentMenu.pipe(takeWhile(() => this.isAlive))
   .subscribe((result: ResultClass) => { 
      if(result && result.name)
      {
         //do stuff
      }
   }
);
```

Comment: Might be some typescript version issue. subscribe(result: any) will fix the issue

Comment: Adding `: any` to the subscription does not fix the issue.

Comment: If using `any` like `subscribe((result: any) => ...)` doesn't help then the problem is somewhere else and not in `takeWhile`.

Comment: @martin ok doing `subscribe((result: any) => ...)` worked. (with the extra brackets). But why do I need to specify the type in my project when on Stackblitz it is automatically carried over from the observable?

Comment: I doubt it's the `takeWhile`, as `const source = of(1).pipe(takeWhile(() => true))` sees `source` inferred to be `Observable<number>`. I think it depends upon the type of `this.menuService.currentMenu` and that's not included in the question.

Comment: @cartant the example shows the classes. As for takewhile... if I remove takewhile and leave pipe empty or remove pipe alltogether and subscribe directly it works. It's only when I pipe AND add takewhile that I lose typing.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The StackBlitz example does not appear to exhibit the problematic behaviour you've detailed in the question.

Comment: @cartant I explained in my post that the example works it stackblitz but does not work in my own environment. Most likely because of version differences.

Comment: I have just tested using filter instead of takewhile and it has the same issue. So the issue seems to be with pipe. I wasnt sure originally because, like i said earlier, if pipe is empty `observable.piple().subscribe(v => {...})` the error disappears. I will update my post for clarity.

Comment: Also, @cartant after adding `const source = of(new ResultData()).pipe(takeWhile(() => true));` to my code... It showed up as `Observable<{}>` in my project. So it is stripping the typing... Again, in stackblitz it works as expected with type of `Observable<ResultData>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to have been cause by a combination of me changing my `node`/`npm` installation to be handled by `nvm` while using an old version of *Visual Studio Code*.

Once I updated to the new *Visual Studio Code 1.24.1* the problem went away.

---

Full explanation:

I think the old version of *Visual Studio Code* didn't know where to look for the `npm` installation. I got an error (not right away, it was about a day after updating to `nvm`) saying something about `npm` and `Automatic Type Acquisition` and found [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_fixing-npm-not-installed-warning-for-automatic-type-acquisition) on how to fix the issue. I could use `npm` through the terminal fine, it just seems to have been causing an issue with this `Automatic Type Acquisition` thing (this is my guess).

I tried using the `which npm` command in `terminal` to find the installation path and put that in the settings file as directed by the article. It didn't seem to fix the issue. This might have been because I used the incorrect path, or I might have forgotten to restart *Visual Studio Code* to have the settings take effect (I think I did restart though), either way I decided to just revert my settings file and update *Visual Studio Code* to see if the new version would play nice with `nvm`.

So my guess is the new *Visual Studio Code* knows about `nvm` and can find the `npm` installation.

It is interesting that it could properly keep the typing if I did a direct `subscribe` on the `observable`. Perhaps upgrading to the new `rxjs` was part of the issue along with the other two things.

Comment: What you say about `nvm` is interesting. In my case, I checked yarn/npm, node, ng version issues but I did not check nvm at all. In the end, out of desperation, I did a git rollback and continued with my previous Angular 5 version.